# Not able to establish websocket connection for a EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

I wanted to deploy a websocket server in the port 8080 in a ec2 instance linux

```
import websockets
import asyncio

PORT = 8080
print(f'Server is listening on port: {PORT}')
connected = set()


async def echo(ws_client, path):
    print('A Client just connected!')
    connected.add(ws_client)
    try:
        async for message in ws_client:
            print('Received message from client:' + message)
            for conn in connected:
                if conn != ws_client:
                    await conn.send(message)

    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
        print('A Client just disconnected!')
    finally:
        connected.remove(ws_client)


server = websockets.serve(echo, 'localhost', PORT)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

but when i run the code in ec2 instance
and run my client
which is

```
import websockets
import asyncio


async def get_input():
    return input()

async def listen():
    url = 'ws://<ec2 instance ip>:8080'
    async with websockets.connect(url) as ws:
        await ws.send('Hello server!')
        while True:
            task = asyncio.create_task(get_input())
            msg = await ws.recv()
            print(msg)
    

asyncio.get_event_loop(). \
    run_until_complete(listen())
```

it is saying the remote system refused to connect

this is my security
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2uVH.png)

i want to deploy a websocket server and that to secure websocket and want my clients to connect to it and chat.
Please help me

Comment: and also to note i tried from my windows system and the connection got refused

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ws` connection on port `8080`, but security group only allows port `80`. So that's why connections to port `8080` are not successful.